# Programming for facebook

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

Im a newbie when it comes to programming for FB.

So a CEO of a magazine asked me to use one of the reading FB apps, and if i could relate the magazine site to the FB page and permit the readers to see the news.

Specificly he wants people to read news in the FB page but without losing the site views by relating the site layout and Google Analytics.

How do i do this?

Comment: Im slightly confused - you would like visitors of facebook or a website ? to see news ? without losing views ? or layout ? or google analytics ? using "one of the reading FB apps" ?

Comment: How is it still "Facebook" at all if you have the magazine site's layout and content? It sounds like the app just redirects them to the magazine's website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Farily straight forward. Create a page tab app.  Point the page tab apps url to that of the magazine site's news page.